# Change the value of a form using BoundField in Django?

Tags: django, forms, filter, django-templates

I am trying to use a custom template filter to change the value of a form and spit it back out. Specifically, I am trying to do what the `cut` template filter already does, but using `lstrip` and `rstrip` instead.

```
from django.template import Library
register = Library()

def lstrip(value, arg):
    return value.value() #I can get the form value, but how do I change it?

register.filter('lstrip',lstrip)
```

In my template:

```
#import custom template tags

{{ form.url|lstrip:"/" }}
```

How do I change the field value and return the field with the new value in place (just like the `cut` filter already does)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, I would change the name of your template tag, because lstrip is a built-in method of python. In your renamed template tag, you can actually use lstrip if that's what you want to do:

```
def my_custom_strip(value, arg):
    return value.lstrip(arg)
```

and in your template

```
{{ form.url|my_custom_strip:"/" }}
```

Hope this helps,

Hoff